# Average the last 6 records entered within the row

Tags: vba, excel

So I've made an Average/Offset formula that averages the last 6 records it sees. For example if I'm working with cells A1 to J1, and I enter values in A1 to H1, it will average values from C1 to H1. And if I add a value in I1, it will average D1 to I1. See the formula below:

```
AVERAGE(OFFSET(A1,0,COUNT(A1:J1)-6,1,6))

AVERAGE(OFFSET(first cell, COUNT(entire range)-N,0,N,1))
```

Here's an example: The average should be 3.5

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
row 1:          4   2   3   4   5   5   2
```

The problem with the offset formula is that if there's a black cell between A1 to J1, it miscalculates because it believes the last data was at the break (if that makes sense). I'm looking for an alternative formula that reads from the right-most value from the selected array (since I'll be adding values to the right all the time).

Comment: Do you want this for a **row** or a **column** ??

Comment: Will there be any **empty** cells between the first data point and the last datapoint ??

Comment: Do you want to include the last 6 cells from the last value or the last 6 values skipping any blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last 6 values in a row, excluding all blanks:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(135:135,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(H135:AA135)/(H135:AA135<>""),6)):INDEX(135:135,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(H135:AA135)/(H135:AA135<>""),1)))
```

Comment: Hi Scott, how do you work around it if there aren't 6 values in the cell? Say there's only 2 input, the formula will come out as a #NUM!. How can you tweak it to be dynamic in a way that it averages out even when there are less than 6 values in place?

=AVERAGE(INDEX(135:135,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(H135:AA135)/(H135:AA135<>""),IF(COUNTA(H135:AA135)<6,COUNTA(H135:AA135),6))):INDEX(135:135,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(H135:AA135)/(H135:AA135<>""),1)))

Answer (score 0):

This small *UDF()* should work for any row or column:

```
Option Base 1

Public Function SuperAverage(rng As Range, N As Long) As Double
    Dim RngCnt As Long, i As Long, Zum As Double, j As Long
    Dim ary() As Double
    ReDim ary(1)

    j = 1
    RngCnt = rng.Count

    For i = RngCnt To 1 Step -1
        If rng(i).Value <> "" Then
            ary(j) = rng(i).Value
            If j = N Then Exit For
            ReDim Preserve ary(j + 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    SuperAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ary)

End Function
```

For example:

[image]

The first argument is the range and the second argument is the item count.

Comment: Both of these are great solution! thank you so much Scott and Gary!